# Implementing AES encryption in F# (according to MSDN C# example)

Tags: .net, encryption, f#, cryptography, aes

Probably I have a stupid question, but I am not able to make it working.
I am doing the AES encryption\decryption in F# according to the MSDN example which is in C#:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes.aspx

My encryption method is as follows:

```
let EncryptStringToBytesAes (plainText : string) (key : byte[]) (iv : byte[]) =
    use aesAlg = Aes.Create()
    aesAlg.Key <- key
    aesAlg.IV <- iv
    // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
    let encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV)
    // Create the streams used for encryption. 
    use msEncrypt = new MemoryStream()
    use csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
    use swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt)
    swEncrypt.Write(plainText)
    msEncrypt.ToArray()
```

The problem is that this method always returns me an empty array of bytes. I do not have any exception. Key and IV are proper arrays of bytes. Seems like the StreamWriter is not working...

Thank you for help.

Comment: As a simplification you can use `encryptor.TransformFinalBlock`. Using `CryptoStream` for short messages is unnecessarily convoluted.

Comment: As a sidenote: 1) an IV needs to be randomly generated for each message. Reusing IVs across messages is not secure. 2) Don't forget to add a proper MAC in an encrypt-then-mac scheme. Else active attacks like padding oracles can easily break your encryption.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To make it working we need to explicitly close the StreamWriter and CryptoStream

Answer (score 5):

Building on @usr's answer...

The easiest way to make sure the stream is closed is to place the `use` statements within a block that goes out of scope before `ToArray` is called.

```
let EncryptStringToBytesAes (plainText : string) (key : byte[]) (iv : byte[]) =
    use aesAlg = Aes.Create()
    aesAlg.Key <- key
    aesAlg.IV <- iv
    // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
    let encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV)
    // Create the streams used for encryption. 
    use msEncrypt = new MemoryStream()
    (
      use csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
      use swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt)
      swEncrypt.Write(plainText)
    )
    msEncrypt.ToArray()
```

Comment: Is there any advantage of parentheses over `do`?

Comment: Only if you're a LISPer.

Answer (score 2):

Before you call `msEncrypt.ToArray` you must flush all intermediate streams, or close them, because they are buffering data.

Comment: I have done the Flush() but it is still not working. I have done like this: swEncrypt.Write(plainText); swEncrypt.Flush(); csEncrypt.Flush(); msEncrypt.ToArray()

Comment: That should work. Use the debugger to find out what the streams contain after each line, and make sure that plainText is not empty.

Comment: I have debugged, the StreamWriter and CryptoStream have the plaintext bytes, but the MemoryStream not...

Comment: Now I get it. You *can't* flush the CryptoStream because that does not make sense. It operates on whole blocks only. It cannot flush a partial block. Close all streams instead.

Comment: Thank you, I have done swEncrypt.Close() and csEncrypt.Close() and now I get the result. But how calling the Close() is affecting that I am using the F# "use" keyword? I guess that it will be closed two times and Microsoft does not recommend such situation.

Comment: Closing multiple times is safe but it would be better style to close once. I don't know enough F# to help you with that. You must shorten the scope of the `use` so that the streams go out of scope before you call `msEncrypt.ToArray()`.